# Mapping roadway distance to polygon using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I need to map the roadway distance from a point to a polygon (or polygon to polygon).

Is this possible in ArcMap?

I know I can't add polygons as a location in Network Analyst so I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think **service area** is what you are looking for.
check out this link:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm

Comment: Thanks, Moshe! Yes, I'm familiar with service area, but it doesn't support polygons as a facility, so I'm looking for a work around.